# Define multiple var clojure macro

Tags: clojure, macros, configuration-files

I have a clojure application that need some configuration variable, mainly string but also stuff to evaluate.

I could just declare every single variable with something like:

```
(def config-db "URI_DB"))
(def config-time (hours 1))
```

But I thought that **might** be a good idea (I am not very sure) write a macro to do that, something that will looks like this:

```
(make-config 
  config-db "URI_DB"
  config-time (hours 1))
```

(Or I can put the names inside a vector to looks more like a let statement)

But I am getting problem when I put more than one couple, I did this:

```
(defmacro define-config
  [name definition]
  `(def ~name ~definition))
```

But I have really no glue to how expand this in something more useful...

Any suggestions or ideas ?

Comment: I know this is very old, but your use case seems to be much better supported by a map, e.g. `(def config {:db "URI_DB" :time (hours 1)})`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I strongly recommend just doing each `def` separately. This macro is trivial but isn't very useful. When someone sees `def`, they know precisely what is going on. When they see your custom `make-config` call, they have to look at the implementation of `make-config` to know what is going on. You get rid of a few characters in large examples and lose readability.

With that said, you can make a macro to do this easily:

```
(defmacro make-config [& forms]
  `(do ~@(for [[name body] (partition 2 forms)]
           `(def ~name ~body))))
```

And an example of usage:

```
user=> (make-config foo "foo" bar (str "b" "a" "r"))
#'user/bar
user=> foo
"foo"
user=> bar
"bar"
```

Comment: Aw. If he called it `setq`, every common lisper would know what he meant.